# Update the values and insert the change in a new table using transactions SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I'm trying to create a new historical table which saves any of the updates that has been made to a table TempLimitBook.

When executing the following code, the table TempLimitBookHistory (hsitorical table) gets two records even if any of the values has been updated.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong in the following code?

```
IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT RecordId
            FROM TempLimitBook 
            WHERE RecordId = @RecordId)
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRAN
            UPDATE TempLimitBook SET 
            LimitName= @LimitName,
            LimitValue= @LimitValue,
            GCN = @GCN,
            watchListFlag = @watchListFlag,
            nextWatchListReview = @nextWatchListReview,
            TotalLimitCurrency = @TotalLimitCurrency,
            TotalLimitAmount = @TotalLimitAmount,
            totalLimitAMountSEK = @totalLimitAMountSEK,
            sTCountryLimitTLCurrency = @sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,
            sTCountryLimitSEK = @sTCountryLimitSEK,
            mTCountryLimitTLCurrency = @mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,
            mTCountryLimitSEK = @mTCountryLimitSEK,
            riskClass = @riskClass,
            accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency = @accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,
            accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK = @accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,
            transactionalPolicyDeviation = @transactionalPolicyDeviation,
            transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK = @transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,
            forbearance = @forbearance,
            nextReviewDate = @nextReviewDate,
            country = @country,
            segment = @segment,
            profitCentre = @profitCentre,
            clientExecutive = @clientExecutive,
            accountManager = @accountManager,
            industryCode = @industryCode,
            active = @active,
            decisionMakingBody = @decisionMakingBody 
        WHERE RecordId = @RecordId

    INSERT INTO 
    TempLimitBookHistory (RecordId,LimitName,LimitValue,GCN,watchListFlag,nextWatchListReview,TotalLimitCurrency,totalLimitAmount,totalLimitAMountSEK,sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,sTCountryLimitSEK,mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,mTCountryLimitSEK,riskClass,accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,transactionalPolicyDeviation,transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,forbearance,nextReviewDate,country,segment,profitCentre,clientExecutive,accountManager,industryCode,active,decisionMakingBody, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedUser) 
    select 
    recordId,limitName,limitValue,GCN,watchListFlag,nextWatchListReview,TotalLimitCurrency,totalLimitAmount,totalLimitAMountSEK,sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,sTCountryLimitSEK,mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,mTCountryLimitSEK,riskClass,accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,transactionalPolicyDeviation,transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,forbearance,nextReviewDate,country,segment,profitCentre,clientExecutive,accountManager,industryCode,active,decisionMakingBody, LastModifiedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LastModifiedUser = SYSTEM_USER
    from TempLimitBook
COMMIT TRAN
END
ELSE

    INSERT INTO TempLimitBook (RecordId,LimitName,LimitValue,GCN,watchListFlag,nextWatchListReview,TotalLimitCurrency,totalLimitAmount,totalLimitAMountSEK,sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,sTCountryLimitSEK,mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,mTCountryLimitSEK,riskClass,accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,transactionalPolicyDeviation,transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,forbearance,nextReviewDate,country,segment,profitCentre,clientExecutive,accountManager,industryCode,active,decisionMakingBody) 
    VALUES 
    (@recordId,@limitName,@limitValue,@GCN,@watchListFlag,@nextWatchListReview,@TotalLimitCurrency,@totalLimitAmount,@totalLimitAMountSEK,@sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,@sTCountryLimitSEK,@mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,@mTCountryLimitSEK,@riskClass,@accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,@accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,@transactionalPolicyDeviation,@transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,@forbearance,@nextReviewDate,@country,@segment,@profitCentre,@clientExecutive,@accountManager,@industryCode,@active,@decisionMakingBody)  
    INSERT INTO 
    TempLimitBookHistory (RecordId,LimitName,LimitValue,GCN,watchListFlag,nextWatchListReview,TotalLimitCurrency,totalLimitAmount,totalLimitAMountSEK,sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,sTCountryLimitSEK,mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,mTCountryLimitSEK,riskClass,accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,transactionalPolicyDeviation,transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,forbearance,nextReviewDate,country,segment,profitCentre,clientExecutive,accountManager,industryCode,active,decisionMakingBody, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedUser) 
    select 
    recordId,limitName,limitValue,GCN,watchListFlag,nextWatchListReview,TotalLimitCurrency,totalLimitAmount,totalLimitAMountSEK,sTCountryLimitTLCurrency,sTCountryLimitSEK,mTCountryLimitTLCurrency,mTCountryLimitSEK,riskClass,accumulatedPolicyDeviationTLCurrency,accumulatedPolicyDeviationSEK,transactionalPolicyDeviation,transactionalPolicyDeviationSEK,forbearance,nextReviewDate,country,segment,profitCentre,clientExecutive,accountManager,industryCode,active,decisionMakingBody, LastModifiedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LastModifiedUser = SYSTEM_USER
    from TempLimitBook

END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first trans part

```
INSERT INTO 
TempLimitBookHistory (***) 
select *    
from TempLimitBook
```

You dont distinct that its a specefik value you want to insert, you insert everything from the TempLimitBook

In the last part you take the full table and insert it into the historytable
is that what you want?

```
INSERT INTO 
TempLimitBookHistory (*) 
select 
*
from TempLimitBook
```

and you should insert it into the history table before you update the value, otherwise you insert the new data if you specify what value you want to insert.

I recommend you to read about Triggers insted
then its auto do this when you update a table.
Update TempLimitBook
then the changed value insrts into TempLimitBookHistory